# Error 3420: Object invalid or no longer set

Tags: vba, excel, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble with a odbc connection in excel-vba tool.

```
Public connString As Connection

    Sub login()
        logout
        Set wrkODBC1 = CreateWorkspace("NewODBC", "admin", "", dbUseODBC)
        Set connString= wrkODBC1.OpenConnection("odbc-database", dbDriverNoPrompt, , "ODBC;uid=user;pwd=passwrd;DSN=odbc-database")
    End Sub

    Sub logout()
        On Error Resume Next
        connString.Close
        wrkODBC1.Close
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Sub
```

When running this code:

```
login
txt = "SELECT [col1],[col1] FROM database.[dbo].[table]"
sqlToWorksheet sheet, connString, txt


Sub sqlToWorksheet(sheet, conn, sqlString)
    Set temp = conn.OpenRecordset(sqlString, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

When conn.OpenRecordset is executed I get the error: Error 3420: Object invalid or no longer set. Anyone knows what wrong? Works with my other odbc connections. The database is a mssqlserver2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot this instantiate wrkODBC1, working now.